# How do you find out how many coins you have collected?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I keep collecting coins which are unlocking loads of upgrades all the time. But how to you find how many coins you have collected in total? Knowing this will give me an idea how much more stuff there is to collect.

Comment: When i got the golden glider i kept counting from where i am about so i have a rough estimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 27 of August 2014 Nintendo released an update for Mario Kart which included this option:

- Drivers will now have the option to display the course map on the TV screen during races
- **Users will be able to check out statistics such as their total number of coins accumulated**, win-loss record from online play, and their most frequently selected character overall
- Users will be able to change options of others’ Mario Kart TV downloaded highlight reels, such as changing the focus to a new character or event
- The order of the menu after each race will be changed to “Next Race”, followed by “Watch Highlight Reel”
- The game will remember the most recent customised kart settings that were selected, even if the Wii U system is powered down
- Improvements to stability of connection in online play to enhance the user experience

Source: [Nintendo](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/News/2014/August/Nintendo-adds-three-Mercedes-Benz-cars-and-enhancements-to-Mario-Kart-8-from-27th-August-909198.html) itself

Comment: "The order of the menu after each race will be changed to 'Next Race', followed by 'Watch Highlight Reel'". About time!

Comment: Indeed. So many misclicks. So much frustration. Finally over. Hooray!

Answer (score 3):

You can't, I was wondering that too and there is no option anywhere. Not even on the Gamepad when posting to Miiverse.

All unlockables:
http://www.ign.com/wikis/mario-kart-8/Unlockables